# Is there a way to convert the results of Stream into Array and iterate through Array elements?

Tags: java, arrays, stream, java-stream

I have created a `Stream` to run recursively through number of files and folders. I need to convert the result of the `Stream` into `Array` and iterate through the results of the `Array`.

I am having problems with the following code:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(start, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        List<String> collect = stream
            .stream().map(x->x.getName())
            .filter(s -> s.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray();

        collect.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    String[] listfiles = new String[stream.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < stream.length; i++) {
       listfiles[i] = stream[].getName();
    }
```

Comment: What problems?  A compilation error?  A runtime error?  It runs but "doesn't work"?

Comment: The problems I get are the following: 
`The method stream() is undefined for the type Stream<Path>`
`stream cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Remove the `.stream()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code you've posted.

1. You call `stream.stream()`

   - The `Stream` class does not have a `stream()` method. It wouldn't make sense for it to have such a method since it's already a stream.
2. You call `x.getName()`

   - At this point, `x` is a `Path` which doesn't have a `getName()` method. You can use `getFileName()`, which returns a `Path`, or `toString()`, which returns the path as a string, or combine the two to only get the file name as a string.
3. You assign `List<String> collect` to the result of `Collection.toArray()`.

   - That method returns an `Object[]`.
4. You use `collect(Collectors.toList())` before calling `toArray()`.

   - The `Stream` class has a `toArray()` method, there's no reason to first collect into a list if an array is the desired end result.
5. You use `toArray()` which returns `Object[]` (both for `Stream` and `Collection`)

   - You want a `String[]` which means, since there's no need to collect first, you need to call [`Stream.toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)).
6. You use `stream` outside the `try` block.

   - Since `stream` is local to the `try` block you can't use it outside the `try` block. There's also no reason for you to use it outside the block as you only need the `String[]` result.
7. You attempt to do something like `stream[]`.

   - A `Stream` is not an array and cannot be accessed like one. Also, a `Stream` is not a container but a pipline; trying to access certain elements in it does not make sense.
   - This also applies to `stream.length` because `Stream` does not have a `length` field (again, because it's not an array).

---

Fixing those problems, your code might look something like the following (based on the current form of your code as I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly):

```
String[] result;
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(start, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    result = stream.map(Path::toString)
            .filter(s -> s.endsWith(".txt"))
            .sorted()
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}

for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

You might also consider using [`Files.find(Path,int,BiPredicate,FileVisitOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#find(java.nio.file.Path,int,java.util.function.BiPredicate,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)) and/or a [`PathMatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html).

Comment: I need to iterate the results and add the results to a new Array. I am trying this but getting no reply. 

`String[] listfiles = result;
     for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      listfiles[i];
         System.out.println("Filename is " + listfiles[i]);
     }`

Comment: "`listFiles[i];`" doesn't do anything. If you want to copy you have to actually add the element from one array to the other. For example: `listFiles[i] = result[i];`. Reading [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), or some [other tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+tutorial), may help you.

Comment: This is the last question: How can I convert Array from `String[]` into `File[]`? Or directly get `File[]` from the `Stream`?

Comment: You can probably create a `File` from the `String` (i.e. use one of the constructors of `File`). Or, if you change your code so it doesn't map `Path` to `String`, you can use `Path.toFile()`.

Comment: I have modified the code, but now getting error for filter `endsWith` 
`File[] result;
     try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(start, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
         result = stream.map(Path::toFile)
                 .filter(s -> s.endsWith(".ttl"))
                 .sorted()
                 .toArray(File[]::new);
     }`

Comment: Yes, because now `s` is a `File` instead of a `String`. You need to modify the `Predicate` used with `filter` to account for this change.